# uwp speech recognition different level control

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition

I'm creating a speech interactive App using UWP. which can show news and weather information, also can play music (I have done that part),but I have some problems about speech recognition:

**The functions that I expect:** 
 first command must include "Jason" to activate the App, after that you just need to say the function you want not need to add Jason anymore (like"show me some news."), and after 30 secs, this activate section end, your command need to add "Jason" again to activate the App.

**The function I have achieved so far:**
Can continuously recognize user's speech, but every command must has "Jason" to trigger the function (like "Jason, show me some news.") 
The following is the code I have used.

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        SpeechRecognizer contSpeechRecognizer =  new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();
        await contSpeechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;


        contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.AutoStopSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;


        await contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }
    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await contSpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }
    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            speechResult = args.Result.Text; 
            try
            {

                if (speechResult.Contains("jason"))
                {
                    Functions();//Control functions
                }
            catch
            {
            }
        });
    }
```

Questions: 1.How can I change to achieve the expected function? 2. Can grammar solve this problem? 3. And how to add the grammar?

Comment: In your code, you always check `if (speechResult.Contains("jason"))`. I'd think this is why you need to always add "Jason"  to make it work.

Comment: @ Scavenger Yes, I'm purposely to do it to reduce false response, since I don't know how to use different level to control the App, so I only can use  "Jason" as a trigger